# Gatsby File System Route API cannot resolve client-path parameter at root

Tags: gatsby, reach-router

I am trying to create a set of dynamic pages at the root of a Gatsby 3 project.
[Gatsby's File System Route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/routing/file-system-route-api/#syntax-client-only-routes) provides the ability to create client-paths using the following syntax

```
[name_goes_here].ext
```

which in turn passes the value of `names_goes_here` to the file `[names_goes_here].ext`.

This functionality works fine when using nested folder structures such as `/app/[user]/..` but results in a 404 when the dynamic folder exists in the root, ex: `/[app]/../..`. However, the failure only occurs on the `index.ext` of the dynamic folder and not in any of its subdirectories / non-index files. `[app]/subdir/...` and `[app]/file.ext` will be resolved but `[app]/index.ext` will not.

Gatsby returns the following error when attempting to request the index file.

```
GET http://localhost:8001/13/undefinedundefined/13/ 404
```

where `13` is the value provided as the path parameter.

File structure (`src/`):

```
.
├── images
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── logo.png
├── index.d.ts
├── pages
│   ├── 404.tsx
│   ├── [app]
│   │   ├── file1.tsx
│   │   └── index.tsx
│   ├── file3.tsx
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── file4.tsx
│   │   ├── file5.tsx
│   │   ├── file6.tsx
│   │   ├── index.tsx
│   │   ├── file7.tsx
│   │   ├── file8.tsx
│   │   ├── subdir2/
│   │   └── file9.tsx
│   ├── file10.tsx
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── file11.tsx
└──
```

Why are the subdirectories being resolved but the index file is not?

Comment: The problem lied with the the `api` call. Amplify sends API calls to the current `base-url`. This made it seem as `gatsby` was the problem, when it was in fact a problem with the url used during the request to the `rest-api`.